# Itemtpl or customizing list for NestedList in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to add images and buttons within items of a nested list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using :

```
 listConfig:{
        itemTpl:'<div id="{category_id}"> {img} <!--<h2>{client_category_id}</h2>--!><p>{text}</p></div>'
            }
```